# Get javascript variable in an html div when display changed to block

Tags: javascript, php, html

I've a table which shows the activities of an user. In table the name of user is an hyperlink which shows the details of that user as popup. In that hyperlink, in href i've called a javascript function which changes the display of the popup to block also i pass the user id to that javascript function.

My task is to get the user id from function to the div which i displayed as block and show user details of that user id in the popup. Can anyone help me to get the user id in div from function.

Here is the code:

html table

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="table table-striped table-bordered bootstrap-datatable" id="datatable">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>
            <input type="checkbox" id="selectall1" class="checkbox1" />
        </th>
        <th>Username</th>
        <th>User ID</th>
        <th>Status</th>
        <th>&nbsp;</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <?php $qry1="select * from tab_user_login where type='Advertiser' and (status='not approved' or status='verified')" ; $res1=mysql_query($qry1); while($row1=mysql_fetch_array($res1)) { $uid=$row1[1]; $status=$row1[6]; ?>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox1" name="chkbox[]" value="<?php echo $uid;?>" />
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row1[2];?>
        </td>
        <td>
            <?php echo $row1[1];?>
        </td>
        <?php switch($status) { case "approved": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-success">approved</span></td>'; break; case "not approved": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">not approved</span></td>'; break; case "rejected": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-danger">rejected</span></td>'; break; case "suspended": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-danger">suspended</span></td>'; break; case "deleted": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">deleted</span></td>'; break; case "stopped": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-danger">stopped</span></td>'; break; case "under review": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">under review</span></td>'; break; case "verified": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">verified</span></td>'; break; case "Approved": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-success">approved</span></td>'; break; case "Not Approved": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">not approved</span></td>'; break; case "Rejected": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-danger">rejected</span></td>'; break; case "Suspended": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-danger">suspended</span></td>'; break; case "Deleted": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">deleted</span></td>'; break; case "Stopped": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-danger">stopped</span></td>'; break; case "Under Review": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">under review</span></td>'; break; case "Verified": echo '<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning">verified</span></td>'; break; } ?>
        <!--<td><span class="label label-sm label-warning"><?php //echo $row1[6];?></span></td>
                                    <td ><a href="" onClick="popupCenter('viewadv.php?advid=<?php echo $uid;?>')">View Details</a></td>-->
        <td><a href="" data-toggle="modal" onClick="showpopup('<?php echo $uid;?>')">View Details</a>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <?php } ?>
</tbody>
```

Popup

```
<div id="box-config-modal1" class="modal hide fade in" style="display: none;">
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
         <h3>ADVERTISER DETAILS</h3>

    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Advertiser Details</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary" data-dismiss="modal">Save Changes</a>
 <a href="#" class="btn" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</a>

    </div>
</div>
```

javascript

```
function showpopup(id)
{
document.getElementById('box-config-modal1').style.display='block';
}
```

Comment: Since you pass the `userid` to the javascript function, make an `ajax` call to get all information for that user and display it in the pop-up. That would be one way..

Comment: I got the solution, tried as u told..